# Search method not working in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, search, razor

I have this search method created on "MusicController":

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
        {
            var musicas = from m in db.Musicas select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                musicas = musicas.Where(s => s.Nome.Contains(search));
               // return RedirectToAction("Search"); //name of view that will return the data
            }
            return View(musicas);
        }
```

This method is called at my _Layout.cshtml:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Music",null, FormMethod.Post, new {@class ="navbar-form navbar-left" , role="search"}))
{
      <div class="form-group">
           @Html.TextBox("search")
      </div>
      button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="search">Submit</button>
}
```

So, when user put a value in TextBox and click on submit button, is redirected to this view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestTcc2.Models.Musica>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutOuvinte.cshtml";
}
<h2>Search</h2>
<table>
       <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Genero</span>
        </th>

        <th>
            <span>Nome</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Artista</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Preço</span>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.genero.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeArtista)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preco)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Play", "", new { path = item.path }) |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

At this view, the user should see the result of search method, I think that I need to put a if after for like "if(item.Nome == "searchResult")", but I don't know what is the best way to put the result of the search method at the table.

Someone can help me? Basically, I need to return the result of the search method at table on Search view.

Comment: What problem are you having? Is a exception being thrown? Is it not returning the results you expect? (you do not need `if(item.Nome == "searchResult")`)

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your model class and related items, I can only suggest that you take a look at what is returned to the View.

Debug your Controller and place a breakpoint on the line:

```
return View(musicas);
```

Check what is in musicas, are the child items there and navigable? You have used:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.genero.Nome)
```

If the genero child item is not available, you will get an error.

Also, is db.Musicas the same as:

```
IEnumerable<TestTcc2.Models.Musica>
```

It is one thing to get data from a database/dataset etc. but it needs to be in the same model structure used on the page.